# late responce on json call from service?

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my HTML, calling a function on click:

```
<span class="hover margin-right-10px pull-left" ng-click="**leadsactivity.addNote(item)**"
                              tooltip="Add Note"
                              tooltip-placement="left"
                              tooltip-trigger="mouseenter">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book edit-font"></i>
                        </span>
```

Here is the function being called in the controller:

```
leadsactivity.addNote = function (item) {
    var obj = {
        leadsactivity: leadsactivity,
        selectedItem: item,
        reuslt: null
    };

    leadsService.getActivityNote(item.id,function (data) {
        if (result) {
            obj.result = result;
        }
        _showNoteDialog(obj);
    });
};
```

A form opens but the problem is that the service didn't send the response data yet, so the form data can't appear.

Finally, here is service:

```
_getActivityNote = function (id,callback) {
        resource.user.getActivity_noteById({ id: id })
          .$promise.then(function (response) {
              if (response.success) {
                  _leadsObject.activityNotes = response.data;
              }
              else
                  notifyService.notifyError("error");
          }, _errorCallback);


        return _leadsObject;
    }
```

The JSON response is late, so the data doesn't appear in the form. What can be done to fix this timing issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correction in controller:

```
leadsactivity.addNote = function (item) {
var obj = {
    leadsactivity: leadsactivity,
    selectedItem: item,
    reuslt: null
};
leadsService.getActivityNote(item.id,function (result) {
    if (result) {
        obj.result = result;
    }
    _showNoteDialog(obj);
});
};
```

Correction in Service:

```
_getActivityNote = function (id,callback) {
    resource.user.getActivity_noteById({ id: id })
      .$promise.then(function (response) {
          if (response.success) {
              _leadsObject.activityNotes = response.data; // what is the purpose of this ??
              callback(response.data);
          }
          else
              notifyService.notifyError("error");
      }, _errorCallback);
}
```

Try this and let me know if(why) it didn't work

Comment: you were not calling the callback in service on successful result retrival

Comment: the best solution would be to just return $promise.then because it in return creates a promise object and you can chain then() calls like that by handling different tasks at different levels but it would require more refactoring in your currently existing code

Comment: callback(response.data); that reduced my effort . thanks alot @gurbakhshish bro <3

Comment: i am facing another problem, inwhich when i add new record from some form then i want to refresh the page on save but on my controller "reload()" function didn't work.kindly help me for this also?

Comment: Can you add the source code of that in a new Question and add the link of that question in comment here

Comment: Kindly have look?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768252/for-page-refresh-route-reload-or-window-location-reload-is-not-working-in