# For page refresh, $route.reload() or $window.location.reload() is not working in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

i am trying to refresh/reload my page after the addition of new record but its not working in my case.
Here is my Controller which calls after the save button from New Record form.

```
leads.save = function (isFormValid) {
                leads.submitted = true;

                if (isFormValid && !leads.exist) {

                    leadsService.addEditLeads(leads, function () {
                        leads.submitted = false;

                        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                        $route.reload();
                    });
                    //$window.location.reload();
                }
            };
```

Here is my Service

```
_addEditLeads = function (leads, callback) {

        var Leads = {
            id: leads.id,
            title: leads.title,
            is_converted: leads.is_converted,
            street_address: leads.street_address,
            email: leads.email,
            lead_name: leads.lead_name,
            first_name: leads.first_name,
            middle_name: leads.middle_name,
            last_name: leads.last_name,
            phone_num: leads.phone_num,
            postal_code: leads.postal_code,
            city: leads.city,
            state: leads.state,
            country: leads.country,
            lead_owner_id: global.User.id,
            lead_source_id: leads.lead_source_id,
            lead_status_id: leads.lead_status_id,
            employees: leads.employees,
            industry_id: leads.industry_id,
            lead_date: new Date(),
            account_id:leads.account_id,
        };
        var Accounts = {
            account_name: leads.account_name,
            address: leads.address,
            phone: leads.phone,
            website: leads.website,
            description: leads.description,
            employees: leads.employees,
            city: leads.city,
            state: leads.state,
            country: leads.country,
            account_owner_id: global.User.id,
            industry_id: leads.industry_id

        };
        resource.user.addEditLead({ Lead: Leads, Accounts: Accounts })
            .$promise.then(function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    if (Leads.id != 0) {
                        //Update record
                        for (var i = 0; i < _leadsObject.data.length; i++) {
                            if (_leadsObject.data[i].id == Leads.id) {
                                _leadsObject.data[i] = Leads;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        notifyService.notifySuccess(Leads.title + " updated successfully");
                    }
                    else {
                        //Add new
                        notifyService.notifySuccess(Leads.title + " added successfully");
                        Leads.id = response.data;
                        if (_leadsObject.data != null)
                            _leadsObject.data.unshift(Leads);
                        else {
                            _leadsObject.data = [];
                            _leadsObject.data.push(Leads);
                        }
                        //callback(response.data);

                    }
                    if (typeof (callback) == 'function') {
                        callback();
                    }
                }

            }, _errorCallback);

    };
```

controller add data in database through MVC and i am using sql server 2012 database.

Kindly Help me out?

Comment: are you sure that you are using `ngRoute`.. if its `ui.router` then it would be `$state.reload()`

Comment: i am using '$route' in like --- leadattendantModule.controller('LeadsController', ['NotificationService', '$scope', 'LeadsService', '$modal', 'ModalService','$route',
function (notifyService, $scope, leadsService , $modal, modalService,$route) ----

Comment: Can you confirm weather Controller `callback` in `leadsService.addEditLeads(leads, callback)` on controller is getting called. You can use debugging (using breakpoints) feature of Chrome dev tools to check that